# Error getting Azure secret value by secret name in python

Tags: python, azure, azure-keyvault, azure-identity

I am receiving the below error when trying to get the secret value,

```
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'token'
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'AzureCliCredential.get_token' was never awaited
```

Code-

#secrets.py

```
   from azure.identity.aio import AzureCliCredential
   from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
    
    
   KVUri = f"https://{keyVaultName}.vault.azure.net"
    
    
   credential = AzureCliCredential()
    
   secret_client = SecretClient(vault_url=KVUri, credential=credential)    
    
   async def get_secret(name: str):
        secret = await secret_client.get_secret(name)
        return secret.value
```

#main.py

```
 async def print_hi(name):
        # Use a breakpoint in the code line below to debug your script.
        print(f'Hi, {name}')  # Press Ctrl+F8 to toggle the breakpoint.
        secret_value = await secrets.get_secret("order-cat-appinsights-instrumentation-key")
        print(f"Secret value is {secret_value}")
       
 
# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(print_hi('PyCharm'))
    # print_hi('PyCharm')
```

Comment: Hi @Auroops, are you using the asynchronous `SecretClient` from the `azure.keyvault.secrets.aio` namespace? [Async section from `azure-keyvault-secrets` README](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/keyvault/azure-keyvault-secrets/README.md#async-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'token' sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'AzureCliCredential.get_token' was never
> awaited

I agree with mycooyp's comment you need to use **`azure.keyvault.secrets.aio`** library to fetch the secret with the **`async`** process.

You can use the below-modified code to get the secret value with a secret name using Python SDK.

**`secret.py`**

```
from azure.identity.aio import AzureCliCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets.aio import SecretClient

keyVaultName="xxxx"
KVUri = f"https://{keyVaultName}.vault.azure.net"

async def get_secret(name: str):
    credential = AzureCliCredential()
    async with SecretClient(vault_url=KVUri, credential=credential) as secret_client:
        secret = await secret_client.get_secret(name)
        return secret.value
```

**`main.py`**

```
import asyncio
import secret

async def print_hi(name):
    print(f'Hi, {name}')
    secret_value = await secret.get_secret("secret3")
    print(f"Secret value is {secret_value}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(print_hi('Azure'))
```

**Output:**

```
Hi, Azure
Secret value is Wxxxxxxx
```

[image]